# creating randomisation order that is equal across both columns and rows

Tags: r

I'm trying to randomize the order for the receipt of 6 drinks (each in a different day) for 40 participants. I want to ensure that every participant get each drink once, **and** that every drink has roughly the same number of occurrences across participants in each day.

I create the data, with participants in columns and days in rows.

```
library(ggplot2)
set.seed(123)
random_order <- as.data.frame(replicate(40, sample(1:6, 6, 
                                                   replace = F)))

random_order$trial <- c(1:6)

random_order
```

Then I check the number of occurrences of each drink within each row / trial, which shows that the frequency of different drinks within trials is **not** uniform:

```
tidyr::pivot_longer(random_order, cols = c(1:40), 
                    names_to = "participant", values_to = "drink_order") |> 
  dplyr::group_by(trial, drink_order) |> 
  dplyr::summarise(count = dplyr::n())
# # A tibble: 36 × 3
# # Groups:   trial [6]
#   trial drink_order count
#   <int>       <int> <int>
# 1     1           1     9
# 2     1           2     8
# 3     1           3     8
# 4     1           4     4
# 5     1           5     5
# 6     1           6     6
# 7     2           1     7
# 8     2           2     4
# 9     2           3    10
# 10    2           4     7
# # … with 26 more rows
```

and look at it with a density plot:

```
tidyr::pivot_longer(random_order, cols = c(1:40), 
                    names_to = "participant", values_to = "drink_order") |> 
  dplyr::group_by(trial, drink_order) |> 
  dplyr::summarise(count = dplyr::n()) |> 
  ggplot(aes(count)) +
  geom_density()
```

[image]

Basically, I want to have a very thin normal curve. How can I make it so that the count column above has a small range during creating the data?

Thanks!

Comment: I'm not sure if you are examining the number of occurrences correctly. Your current code creates a 6 row by 40 column matrix. In each  column, each number appears exactly once, so it is intuitive that each number has 40 occurrences. If you run `table(unlist(random_order))` you will see that each value `1`, `2`, ... ,`6` appears exactly 40 times. Could you clarify what you are wanting?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You’re looking for a variation on a [Latin square](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Latin_square), which is a set of ordered elements such that each element occurs exactly once per column and once per row. You can generate random Latin squares using `agricolae::design.lsd()`. In your case, instead of *once* per row, you want each element to occur *the same number of times* per row, which you can do by binding together multiple Latin squares.

```
library(agricolae)
set.seed(123)

# to get 40 columns, first get 7 Latin squares
# (7 squares x 6 columns per square = 42 columns)
orders <- replicate(
  7, 
  design.lsd(1:6)$sketch, 
  simplify = FALSE
)
# then column-bind and subset to 40 columns
random_order <- data.frame(do.call(cbind, orders))[, 1:40]
random_order$trial <- c(1:6)
```

Using the code from your question, we can see that all trials include 6 or 7 of each drink:

```
# A tibble: 36 × 3
# Groups:   trial [6]
   trial drink_order count
   <int> <chr>       <int>
 1     1 1               7
 2     1 2               7
 3     1 3               7
 4     1 4               6
 5     1 5               6
 6     1 6               7
 7     2 1               7
 8     2 2               6
 9     2 3               6
10     2 4               7
# … with 26 more rows
```

Comment: This is what I was looking for. Very informative, thank you!